# Fastcgi 502 c++ when FCGX_GetParam Cookie

Tags: c++, cookies, nginx, fastcgi

my code run smoothly without this line.(i just comment this line)

```
std::string cookie;
cookie = FCGX_GetParam("HTTP_COOKIE", request.envp);
```

when this line is uncommented, the code still run smoothly with client that sent the cookies, but something break the system when the client don't have a cookie. what will be the problem of it? Even i use a `try {} catch (...) {}` the code still crash, and will cause 502 for the fastcgi.
the when the code crash

```
upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream
```

this error message was record in nginx error log. then the cgi is not working anymore with connection refused. I need to respawn it to get the code work again.

Answer (score 0):

Oh gosh! I figured it out.
I look back to the fastcgi doc.

Results: Value bound to name, NULL if name not present in the environment envp.  Caller must not mutate the result or retain it past the end of this request.

because if there is not cookie, it will return NULL, the doc said it must not mutate the result.
so the problem can solve by this
std::string cookie;

```
if (FCGX_GetParam("HTTP_COOKIE", request.envp) != NULL){
   cookie = FCGX_GetParam("HTTP_COOKIE", request.envp);
}
```